# Feathers JS - Create multi entries - dumb question

Tags: javascript, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

following the documentation I realize there's an option to allow bulk creation, but I don't understand where and how to set the option, here the code:

```
// Initializes the `test` service on path `/test`
const createService = require('feathers-sequelize');
const createModel = require('../../models/test.model');
const hooks = require('./test.hooks');

module.exports = function (app) {
  const Model = createModel(app);
  const paginate = app.get('paginate');


//Where to put the multi option???
  const options = {
    Model,
    paginate
  };

  // Initialize our service with any options it requires
  app.use('/test', createService(options));

  // Get our initialized service so that we can register hooks
  const service = app.service('test');

  service.hooks(hooks);
};
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the original code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option is added to the `options` object:

```js
// Initializes the `test` service on path `/test`
const createService = require('feathers-sequelize');
const createModel = require('../../models/test.model');
const hooks = require('./test.hooks');

module.exports = function (app) {
  const Model = createModel(app);
  const paginate = app.get('paginate');


//Where to put the multi option???
  const options = {
    Model,
    paginate,
    multi: [ 'create' ] // list of method names
    // or for everything
    // multi: true 
  };

  // Initialize our service with any options it requires
  app.use('/test', createService(options));

  // Get our initialized service so that we can register hooks
  const service = app.service('test');

  service.hooks(hooks);
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I solved it yesterday, but now I have another issue with not at all clues. After a successfully multi-create i have back the response but with all id(s) set to Null.
 [
    {
        "id": null,
        "text": "entity1",
        "createdAt": "2019-03-20T14:11:03.448Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-03-20T14:11:03.448Z"
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "text": "entity2",
        "createdAt": "2019-03-20T14:11:03.448Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-03-20T14:11:03.448Z"
    }
]
Any idea?

Comment: how to implement multi patch and remove, without using multi: ['patch', 'remove'] in service?